# How do I set DNS Servers on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, opendns

I want my Raspberry Pi to use OpenDNS to resolve domain names. How can I modify this setting?

Comment: what OS are you using?  There are multiple OSs for the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Note for future users finding this answer via Google etc: Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` isn't really the right way going about this anymore: You need to edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using Debian on Raspberry Pi, then you need to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

then add the server IP of the openDNS

```
nameserver  208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Btw, if you have any concern about speed of the DNS you may want to take a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/169279/should-i-use-my-isps-dns-or-googles-8-8-8-8)

Comment: I did this, but it's still not using OpenDNS.

Comment: you restarted your board and are using Debian-server, right? If it is the case, please try to add `nameserver 208.67.220.220``and `nameserver 208.67.222.222` to `/etc/network/interfaces`then restart your board or do `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. If it is still not working, please paste output of `dig google.com`

Comment: Should the IPs be in both `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: The /etc/resolv.conf entry is created from the /etc/network/interfaces config.  Note: this works only if you're using static network configuration.  If you're using dynamic settings, then you'll need to change the settings provided by the DHCP server.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that today out of the blue, my Pi3 device couldn't see mirrordetector.raspbian.org. I added the OpenDNS addresses and it works fine. (I had Google's in there...)

Answer (score 51):

I've found that in the latest version of Raspbian (stretch I think?) you now need to edit the last line of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. There should be a line that starts with `static domain_name_servers=` - there you can customise it with a list of space-separated DNS servers, like this:

```
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 208.69.38.205 8.8.8.8
```

*DNS Servers Featured: [Cloudflare](https://1.0.0.1/), [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/), and [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)*

**Edit:** As @DavidOliver points out, you may need to restart dhcpcd too: `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I am using raspbian for the raspberry pi

Comment: This one was the one that worked for me on Raspbian - From the other answers in this question, edits directory to resolv.conf got overwritten on reboot and the network/interfaces edits were ignored

Comment: This should be the correct answer for latest (Raspbian Stretch or Debian Stretch), the accepted answer in 2013 and the higher vote so far of modifying `etc/resolv.conf` are simply no longer correct.

Comment: Seemed like a restart of the service was necessary: `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`

Comment: This worked for me, what a hot mess, why are there 3 ways to change the dns names in raspbian alone?

Comment: @TomasZubiri It's actually changed quite a bit over the years. The method Described in my answer is most up-to-date version. Answers that suggest to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` are outdated because that file is now automatically populated with the current DNS resolution settings, and is auto-updated by NetworkManager/systemd/whatever.

Answer (score 32):

Don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` since that file is generated automatically. Instead edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following to the end:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: resolv.conf is just overwritten by the resolvconf tool. If this tool is not installed the first answer will work. But your solution will work anyway, that's why it should be marked as the right solution.

Comment: this worked for me on raspian stretch lite, thanks!

Comment: didn't work. startbeamrainbowlabs' solution worked!

Answer (score 6):

I have found the answer from another [website](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/dhcpcd.html) and this is the best. I used  the very last part of the article as Raspbian comes with dchpcd already installed and i still want an automatic ip address not a static ip address. Running from a Raspberry Pi3 multiboot [berryboot] with Raspbian - Pixel type

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf.head
```

in your terminal. 
You will have a blank slate to work with. Next copy and paste the following code:

```
#OpenDns Servers
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

click on cntrl + x to exit out and select y for the following options to save.
restart your Raspberry Pi with

```
sudo reboot
```

To make sure you are using OpenDNS go to the following website:
[OpenDns welcome page](https://www.opendns.com/welcome/)

Comment: Could you add a link to the original forum source you found this answer on?

Comment: I have found the exact link [old article from 2013 but works!] I have updated my answer to reflect the link

Comment: Sweet. Context almost always makes a question better.

Comment: I hope this has helped you. By the way the bootloader i use for my  Raspberry PI3 is berryboot [http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot] and i love it! I have Raspbian-Pixel, Kali Linux2.0, OSMC, and RetroPie v3.6 running on a 16GB sd card without having to change sd cards. You can get the images for berryboot here: [http://berryboot.alexgoldcheidt.com/images/] In fact I'm using Raspbian and chromium to answer you.

Comment: This worked for me. I really don't understand why setting up networks is becoming more and more complex and intransparent over time....

THanks for your help!

Comment: This worked for me...in a kind of surprising (reverse) way. The file /etc/resolv.conf.head was *not* empty in my case; instead, it referred to three unwanted DNS server addresses (including 127.0.0.1, where no DNS server is running...). No clue where this came from. In any case, all I had to do was to delete these three unwanted lines, restart dhcpcd (sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service) and everything was fine again (with the correct DNS server address received via DHCP).

Answer (score -2):

The openDNS servers worked for me thanks.
During a Udemy learning session I had run into a problem after ditching my wifi sharing arrangement with my Mac, and setting up ethernet hub with the PI on a different home network.
The problem with my previous IP sharing arrangement with WiFi.

When I originally setup the PI with the sharing arrangement the text Inside the resolve file was:​

```
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

which was entered automatically by the minibian OS,  NOT ME!

This IP became the default DNS server, with the MacMini seamlessly providing the real DNS in the background.
​

SO NEED TO EDIT(vim) WITH

```
nameserver  208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

​Then I could ping google.com
Thank goodness for forums!

Comment: What does this do and how will it help? Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: The instructions here are incomplete. Which file needs editing? Where is it located? Are there any other steps one must complete before your solution solves the issue, and how can one verify the issue is solved?

Answer (score -3):

Add this line into file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.8, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

Then it will work.

Comment: The first IP address is a random private address. The other two are the IP addresses of Google servers - not OpenDNS.