# Transmission doesn't connect internet after ip address change

Tags: networking, download, raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission

After I've changed ip address on raspberry pi I've got problem with torrent client Transmission. It doesn't start download or upload of torrent file.
I've updated `/etc/network/interfaces`, but it doesn't work.

Transmission just doesn't start download or upload!

If I change ip address to old address/network

> 192.168.1.0

it works fine, but in new address

> 192.168.25.0

it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the netmask and default gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I've got solved the problem here in this blog by reading this post: [How do I set DNS Servers on Raspberry Pi?](https://superuser.com/questions/617796/how-do-i-set-dns-servers-on-raspberry-pi)

In the begining I had a dhcp client. After I've changed to static ip updating `/etc/network/interfaces`.
It had written `/etc/resolv.conf` with dns configuration on

> 192.168.1.0

network. When I've update my network to

> 192.168.25.0

I didn't know that I had to update this file, `/etc/resolv.conf`.
After I've updated /etc/resolv.conf my transmission client started work fine again

thanks!